# How do I combine/Merge records in 2 separate access tables

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables: Table One with 3 columns and Table Two with 15 columns. The 3 columns are same name in both Tables

I want to compare the 2 tables and then when it matches 2 specific columns (title & artist) over write the 3rd column (BPM) and leave other 14 columns as is

I expect the BPM Column from Table One to overwrite BPM column in Table 2 when it matches the 2 Columns (Title & Artist)and leave the rest of Table 2 as is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a query that joins the two tables on title and artist fields and then make it an UPDATE action.

```
UPDATE Table2 INNER JOIN Table1 ON Table1.title=Table2.title AND Table1.artist=Table2.artist 
SET Table2.BPM = Table1.BPM
```

Or don't have BPM field in table 2 and just build query whenever need to view related data from both tables.

Comment: I am fairly new to access can you give me more details how I go about your suggestion?

Comment: Use Access query designer. I provided SQL syntax for an UPDATE action. This is basic Access functionality. Have you studied an introductory tutorial book?